# Not able to run sample sso example travelocity.com on WSo2 identity server

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to run the sample travelocity.com on my tomcat web server and use WSO2 Identity server as as Identity provider (IdP). I deployed travelocity.com.war on my local tomcat and accessed the application with  `http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com` , it got re-directed to WSo2 identity server to  `https://localhost:9443/samlsso` and gave error as

```
  "SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
    Error when processing the authentication request!
    Please try login again."
```

The error in my catalina.log file in local tomcat is

```
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Users\258155\Desktop\Tomcat\webapps\SAMLTestTool has finished in 359 ms
Jul 27, 2016 3:22:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 27, 2016 3:22:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 27, 2016 3:22:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 28075 ms
Jul 27, 2016 3:36:50 PM org.wso2.sample.is.sso.agent.SSOAgentSampleFilter doFilter
INFO: SAML2 HTTP Binding not found in request. Defaulting to HTTP-POST
```

Have not made any changes to travelocity.properties file which got generated with sample war and is default one

```
#  Copyright (c) WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved.
#
#  WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
#  Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
#  in compliance with the License.
#  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
#  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
#  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
#  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
#  specific language governing permissions and limitations
#  under the License.


EnableSAML2SSOLogin=true
EnableOpenIDLogin=true
EnableOAuth2SAML2Grant=false

#Url to do send SAML2 SSO AuthnRequest
SAML2SSOURL=samlsso

#Url to do initiate OAuth2 SAML2 Grant Request
OAuth2SAML2GrantURL=token

#Url to initiate OpenID Authentication Request
OpenIdURL=openid

#URIs to skip SSOAgentFilter; comma separated values
SkipURIs=/travelocity.com/index.jsp

#A unique identifier for this SAML 2.0 Service Provider application
SAML2.SPEntityId=travelocity.com

#The URL of the SAML 2.0 Assertion Consumer
SAML2.AssertionConsumerURL=http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/home.jsp

#A unique identifier for this SAML 2.0 Service Provider application
SAML2.IdPEntityId=localhost

#The URL of the SAML 2.0 Identity Provider
SAML2.IdPURL=https://localhost:9443/samlsso

#Identifier given for the Service Provider for SAML 2.0 attributes 
#exchange
#SAML2.AttributeConsumingServiceIndex=1701087467

#Specify if SingleLogout is enabled/disabled
SAML2.EnableSLO=true

#This is the URL that is used for SLO
SAML2.SLOURL=logout

#Specify if SAMLResponse element is signed
SAML2.EnableResponseSigning=true

#Specify if SAMLAssertion element is signed
SAML2.EnableAssertionSigning=true

#Specify if SAMLAssertion element is encrypted
SAML2.EnableAssertionEncryption=false

#Specify if AuthnRequests and LogoutRequests should be signed
SAML2.EnableRequestSigning=true

#Password of the KeyStore for SAML and OpenID
KeyStorePassword=wso2carbon

#Alias of the IdP's public certificate
IdPPublicCertAlias=wso2carbon

#Alias of the SP's private key 
PrivateKeyAlias=wso2carbon

#Private key password to retrieve the private key used to sign 
#AuthnRequest and LogoutRequest messages
PrivateKeyPassword=wso2carbon

#OAuth2 token endpoint URL
OAuth2.TokenURL=https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

#OAuth2 Client ID
OAuth2.ClientId=Qn5DQHCYfshxeZh6R9SL1HM2lsMa

#OAuth2 Client Secret
OAuth2.ClientSecret=cbkAs1gajdwPAMbrSR54hPAIcz0a

#OpenId Provider Url
OpenId.ProviderURL=https://localhost:9443/openid/

#openid.return_to parameter
OpenId.ReturnToURL=http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com/home.jsp

#Custom SAML post binding request page
#SAML.PostBinding.RequestPage=path/to/the/html

#Additional request parameters
#QueryParams=tenantDomain=-1234

#SAML2.IsForceAuthn=true

#Specify whether the consumer requests user attributes from the provider
OpenId.EnableAttributeExchange=true

#Specify whether the consumer runs in dumb mode
OpenId.EnableDumbMode=false
```

The Service Provider settings at WSo2 identity server is default and as asked in the article

```
  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0
```

I have two questions 
(1) What is the reason for error thrown while running and accesing sample travelocity.com application using SAMl SSO
(2) If i have to implement the SAMl SSO using WSO2 identity server in my already running java application ( without Single Sign-On ), what changes have to be done at my application end. because here we can see there is travelocity.properties file and some coding ( around 4 files:- ForwardingServlet.java, SampleAttributesRequestor.java, SampleContextEventListener.java, SSOAgentSampleFilter.java) to redirect the first request to Identity provider  https://localhost:9443/samlsso
What changes i will have to do at my application end.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take a minute and read this tutorial for better questions, especially examples about good and bad titles: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - everything else looks good!

Comment: Did you found the catch. I am too getting the same issue. Followed the documentation and the blogs.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow step by step guide in [1] for setting up travelocity app.

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2015/04/setup-travelocitycom-sample-web-app.html

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the [WSO2 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Single+Sign-On) to configure the travelocity.com web app.
First you need to login to the WSO2 IS 5.1.0 and then need to create service provider in SAML 2.0 for travelocity.com web app. Refer the link documentation for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error. Turns out that I pulled from a branch which was a different version than my WSO2 version. Once I did a 'git checkout' of the correct branch which was v.5.7.0, everything worked fine.